# Create View with data (not repeated) from 2 tables with the same structure

Tags: sql, oracle

In a oracle database, I have 2 tables with the same structure (same columns). One is being migrated to the other. The thing is that I need to create a view that reads records from the 2 tables so that during migration it's possible to read all records. In case there are repeated records, only the ones from table 1 should be displayed in the view.

Table 1

```
USER_ID       START_DATE       END_DATE
1             2015-08-12       2015-12-08
2             2015-02-25       2015-06-01
3             2015-04-14       2015-09-21
```

Table 2

```
USER_ID       START_DATE       END_DATE
2             2015-02-25       2015-06-01
4             2015-12-20       2016-01-13
```

The view should contain the following data:

```
USER_ID       START_DATE       END_DATE
1             2015-08-12       2015-12-08
2             2015-02-25       2015-06-01
3             2015-04-14       2015-09-21
4             2015-12-20       2016-01-13
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Any duplicates in one of table that you want to keep? Otherwise do a `UNION`.

Comment: could the start/end dates in table2 for a given user_id be different in table1 for the same userid, or would they always be the same? Also, is user_id either the primary key or unique?

Comment: @jarlh if there are duplicates, the rows from table 1 should take precedence

Comment: @Boneist for the same user id maybe the dates are different, but in that case the ones from table 1 should be displayed

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it does what u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for, less verbose than the answer from sagi

```
select *
from table1
union all
select *
from  table2 a
where  not exists (select null from table1 where user_id = a.user_id);
```

Comment: listen, first of all what you wrote here is the same as my first query -> select * from table1 union select * from table2, union(and not union all) does what you WHERE clause is doing , so basically i answer your question not you..

Comment: And second, you told me that a duplicated means that all 3 rows exists, thats why i've edited the post and did the full outer join, and you are not checking it. So.. accualy I'm supposed to get the V:)

Comment: I'm sorry @sagi but it's not the same, because with your query duplicated records are not included. with the where condition I added in the second select, they are included (because since they are excluded from the second query they are not duplicated)

Answer (score 2):

If when you say repeated records you mean that all 3 columns are the same, than I don't understand why you want them from table a since they are the same.

In addition, you can just create view as:

```
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
```

that will eliminate all duplicates and basically will keep those from table1 since its the first table(although it doesn't matter)

If you are stubborn on doing it like you said maybe because not all the columns needs to be the same.

then what you need is a full outer join

```
SELECT case when a.id is not null then a.id else b.id end as id,
case when a.id is not null then a.start_date else b.start_date end as start_date,
case when a.id is not null then a.end_date else b.end_date as end_Date
from table a full outer join table2 b on (a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Hi @sagi, thanks for your time. Just one thing: if a row exists in table 1, all columns from that table should be used, and not from table 2. The only case in which a row from table 2 is displayed is that the pk does not exist in table 1. In your answer, if a column in table 1 has a null value it will take the value from table 2, but it should take the one from table 1 (maybe null is a possible value). makes sense?

Comment: Edited my answer.. It will check all by the id @damian